# jqGrid - Column Chooser not working as expected

Tags: jqgrid

Have a look at this url:
http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jquery_ui_methods#column_chooser
I have got the Column Chooser dialog opening up and I can remove columns and when I click OK, it removes or adds columns. When I try reordering columns and click on Ok, it does not do anything. Do I have to override the "done" method? as described in article. At the moment
I am not passing in the options the columnChooser call.
grid.jqGrid('columnChooser') //no options passed.
What do I need to do in order to save the column order?

Comment: @Oleg I had a look at : http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithColumnChooser.htm and thisseems to be working for what I expect but mine is not saving the reordered columns.

Comment: Could you post any code which can be used to reproduce your problem? The overwriting of the `done` method is needed only is you need to do some *additional* custom action on the column reordering. For example if you need adjust width of some elements on the page or to save the column position on the server or in the `localStorage` and so on. I can imagine that there are exist a bug in `columnChooser`. If I would have a demo which reproduce the problem I could try to help you.

Comment: Ill post you the code tomorrow

Comment: @Oleg just found out that it works in IE9 and not in IE7 or IE8.Its the ui.multiselect.js when it tries to applychanges using $widget....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right. I could reproduce some problems in IE8 in [the old demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithColumnChooser.htm) which use old version of jqGrid, jQuery and jQuery UI, but [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithColumnChooser3.htm) which uses all last version: jqGrid 4.3.1, jQuery 1.7.1 and jQuery UI 1.8.17 seems have no the problems.

As the code I used

```js
$grid.jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#pager', {
    caption: "",
    buttonicon: "ui-icon-calculator",
    title: "Choose columns",
    onClickButton: function () {
        $(this).jqGrid('columnChooser');
    }
});
```

Comment: Is it possible that we get a version working in IE7 and 8 and 9? Something seems to not make it work in IE8.Don't know if it's that Compatibility mode thing. I'll check in tomorrow morning and let you know.

Comment: @chugh97: If you have some problems with the IE compatibility mode you can also try to include in the header of the page `<meta content='IE=Edge' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'/>` and repeat the same experiment.

Comment: I updated the jQuery.ui, jquery and the jqGrid to version 4.3.1 and it works fine on IE8 now. Thanks for your help.Very much appreciated...

Comment: @chugh97: You are welcome! I didn't have enough time to examine *why* the previous version didn't work in IE8. So we can hope that the problem is really solved. If you do find later any problem you can post me about.